# How to type check a function that returns different types based on argument values?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes an argument and returns a different type of value based on that argument's value.

For example:

```
function foo(arg: 'a' | 'b') {
  if (arg === 'a') {
    return { prop1: 'hello', prop2: 123 };
  } else {
    return [1, 2, 3];
  }
}
```

I'm trying to type check this function, but I'm not sure how to do it. Specifically, I want to ensure that if the argument is 'a', the returned value has the properties prop1 and prop2, and if the argument is 'b', the returned value is an array of numbers.

I've tried using conditional types, but I'm not quite sure how to get them to work. Can someone help me out?

Comment: This really depends on what you mean by "type check" and whether or not you care about the caller's perspective, the implementer's perspective, or both.  [This playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WyqPbW) shows various options and their drawbacks.  I'm happy to write this up as an answer but could you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```
function foo(arg: 'a'): { prop1: string; prop2: number };
function foo(arg: 'b'): number[];
function foo(arg: 'a' | 'b') {
  if (arg === 'a') {
    return { prop1: 'hello', prop2: 123 };
  } else {
    return [1, 2, 3];
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBDATgcwFyIDkGhAlAQN6IAOWc1AjAQM5RYxg4DcNd1ATATAgAtgCMAplkQBfLgChQkWAmSpMuAoTFkhoyVgDaAXQVLo8JCnTZ8REogA%20RHaUQV5iRDGCINORABeYPsyd08vRCwJKBAsJCpaeiYiAAsJABsMuEIAGl56QUQGfgBmWQUvGURM5glwyKiYuKRDBnz%20fNLTCJl5PvkIBFYm5iC1dGIySsbEAHo5gD0AfnlB4ahR-nHrNG1piMaFlfkgA)